# Sum of fields between two dates in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm very new to ElasticSearch

I want to sum of salary between two dates 27/08/2020 and 31/08/2020 which I'm not able to achieve.

I'm posting here the simple query and the outcome of the query.

I read about date-histogram but could not find a specific answer and If the outcome is very simple then why date-histogram is asking to put in interval as well as it returns data in the bucket.

Documents in employees index are

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "employees",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "wO8AMXQBDHla7ClA8iDV",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "FirstName": "JOYE",
                    "LastName": "WIATR",
                    "Designation": "CEO",
                    "Salary": 144000,
                    "DateOfJoining": "25/05/2009",
                    "Address": "9068 SW. Grove St. Waynesboro, PA 17268",
                    "Gender": "Female",
                    "Age": 58,
                    "MaritalStatus": "Unmarried",
                    "Interests": "Renting movies,Scuba Diving,Snowboarding,Butterfly Watching,Dumpster Diving,Badminton,Church/church activities"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "employees",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "wu8CMXQBDHla7ClAwCDT",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "FirstName": "Ajay",
                    "LastName": "Jaiswal",
                    "Designation": "CEO",
                    "Salary": 44000,
                    "DateOfJoining": "28/08/2020",
                    "Address": "Hyderabad",
                    "Gender": "Male",
                    "Age": 29,
                    "MaritalStatus": "Unmarried",
                    "Interests": "Watching movies , learing from scratch"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "employees",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "w-8KMXQBDHla7ClAICC9",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "FirstName": "MR.X",
                    "LastName": "Jaiswal",
                    "Designation": "CEO",
                    "Salary": 56000,
                    "DateOfJoining": "30/08/2020",
                    "Address": "Hyderabad",
                    "Gender": "Male",
                    "Age": 39,
                    "MaritalStatus": "Married",
                    "Interests": "Watching movies,Watching war movies"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my query

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "DateOfJoining": {
              "gte": "27/08/2020",
              "lte": "31/08/2020"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the outcome of the query

```
{
    "took": 11,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "employees",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "wu8CMXQBDHla7ClAwCDT",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "FirstName": "Ajay",
                    "LastName": "Jaiswal",
                    "Designation": "CEO",
                    "Salary": 44000,
                    "DateOfJoining": "28/08/2020",
                    "Address": "Hyderabad",
                    "Gender": "Male",
                    "Age": 29,
                    "MaritalStatus": "Unmarried",
                    "Interests": "Watching movies , learing from scratch"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "employees",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "w-8KMXQBDHla7ClAICC9",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "FirstName": "MR.X",
                    "LastName": "Jaiswal",
                    "Designation": "CEO",
                    "Salary": 56000,
                    "DateOfJoining": "30/08/2020",
                    "Address": "Hyderabad",
                    "Gender": "Male",
                    "Age": 39,
                    "MaritalStatus": "Married",
                    "Interests": "Watching movies,Watching war movies"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm really not able to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sum of salary between two dates 27/08/2020 and 31/08/2020 which I'm not able to achieve.

**Try below query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "DateOfJoining": {
        "gte": "27/08/2020",
        "lte": "31/08/2020"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sum_of_salary": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "Salary"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I read about date-histogram but could not find a specific answer and
> If the outcome is very simple then why date-histogram is asking to put
> in interval as well as it returns data in the bucket.

In Date-histograms data is bucketized based on some time period.

e.g if you want to get sum of salaries paid to employees month over month, then date-histogram will help there.

Comment: Thanks @Sahil Gupta it got working for me,could you please explain me how does this query gets executed.
Like why size 0 , then how query part executed and at the end aggs.
Please explain for my understanding.

Comment: Best way to explore such things is to read the docs and play with them. 1. size=0 represents we don't want any query results (only aggregation). 2. Query part first filter the data, on which aggregation is applied

Comment: Thank you so much @Sahil Gupta.